# SQL Min and Max for multiple rows

Tags: sql, max, min

I have a table with values like:

```
Name  Test  Score
Bob   Test1 97.0
Bob   Test2 96.5
Bob   Test3 94.5
Joe   Test1 96.5
Joe   Test2 98.5
Joe   Test3 92.0
```

I would like the `MIN` and `MAX` score for each `Name` on one row, like:

```
Name  Min_Score  Max_Score
Bob   94.5       97.0
Joe   92.0       98.5
```

I can get the `MIN` or `MAX` by itself, but not sure how to get both at the same time.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: `select name, min(score) as Min_score, max(score) as max_score from table group by name`

Comment: MSSQL...I tried that but both values equaled the same thing.

Comment: @macbb, then you were not doing a min() and max() functions on both (or you have some records where the min and max are the same) such as would be the case when a user only has one score recorded...

Answer (score 4):

You can group your selection by name.  This will provide you with each unique name.  You can also use aggregate functions min and max that will scan your table for each unique name.  This is a common request:

```
SELECT 
  name
  , min(score) as Min_score
  , max(score) as max_score 
FROM table 
GROUP by name
```

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/DROKH99014) of the query and the correct results

Comment: Thank you, my results were throwing me off. I had a lot of scores that were the same min and max values so I thought it was not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `group by` on user name

```
select distinct tname, 
min(tscore) as min_score, 
max(tscore) as max_score 
from test_table 
group by tname;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/302fd3/1 , http://ideone.com/YmHA7x